# Complex named match group RegEx review

Tags: regex, powershell

From this example string

```
$logLine = '{header[3]}_Pragmatic Praxis Initialization Log'
```

I am trying to extract three pieces of data

- `header` as type
- `3` as an (optional) tab value
- everything after that `_` as a string

What I have now is

```
$logLine = '{header[3]}_Pragmatic Praxis Initialization Log'
if ($logLine -match '^\{(?<type>[a-z]+)(?:\[?(?<tab>\d?)\]?)\}_(?<string>.+)$') { 
    Write-Host "$($matches['type'])"
    Write-Host "$($matches['tab'])"
    Write-Host "$($matches['string'])"
}
```

And it's working well. But I am so unskilled in RegEx, and this is by far the most  complex RegEx I have ever cobbled together from scratch, that I am wondering if anyone sees a gotcha in this approach that I am not seeing?

Or do I need to open some wine and celebrate reaching some sort of RegEx comprehension milestone?

EDIT:
So my success made me over confident. I decided to make Tab required, but add an optional Target which can be either 'console' or 'file'. So I did this

```
$logLine = '{header[3]}_Pragmatic Praxis Initialization Log'
if ($logLine -match '^\{(?<type>[a-z]+)(?:-(?<target>(console|file)))\[(?<tab>\d*)\]\}_(?<string>.+)$') { 
    Write-Host "$($matches['type'])"
    Write-Host "$($matches['target'])"
    Write-Host "$($matches['tab'])"
    Write-Host "$($matches['string'])"
}
```

Which works a treat when target is present, but fails when it is not. So, looks like I get to learn something, rather than celebrate. ;)

EDIT #2:
Per @Ansgar Wiechers, I was indeed misunderstanding `(?:...)`, specifically confusing it for `(....)?`. based on that, this is my revised pattern, which seems to be doing what I want. I may still make both target and tab required, since I think it makes the code more readable while also simplifying the RegEx pattern, but still good to have it working as I initially intended it to work too.

```
if ($logLine -match '^\{(?<type>[a-z]+)(-(?<target>(console|file)))?(\[(?<tab>\d+)\])?\}_(?<string>.+)') { 
    Write-Host "$($matches['type'])"
    Write-Host "$($matches['target'])"
    Write-Host "$($matches['tab'])"
    Write-Host "$($matches['string'])"
}
```

Comment: The match will fail if the number becomes 2 digit. Shown [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/w31OOx/1). Update the Regex to [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/w31OOx/2) to avoid that issue.

Comment: @Gurman. Good point. It may be worth changing that, even though I suspect it will never actually get above 5. If anything I should capture 2 digits then validate the actual value perhaps.

Comment: `\d+` would force the regex to match at least one digit. But you said that it is optional, hence I changed it to `\d*` instead of `\d+`

Comment: @gurman as I am looking at it now, I am starting to think that, since I control that tab value, maybe I should make it non optional, and use [0] where there is no tab, so I can keep the regEx as simple as possible. Matching multiple digits might make sense, or I may keep it looking for one digit and throw an error when the log string is poorly formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you're misunderstanding what `(?:...)` does. That construct does not define an *optional* match, but a *non-capturing group*. A (sub)expression `(?:-(?<target>console|file))` will require the string to contain either `-console` or `-file` and return `console` or `file` (without the leading hyphen) as a named match "target". To make the group optional you need to add another `?` *after* the group.

```
^\{(?<type>[a-z]+)(?:-(?<target>console|file))?\[(?<tab>\d*)\]\}_(?<string>.+)
#                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

Note that a trailing expression `.+` or `.*` makes anchoring the expression at the end of the string (`$`) pointless, so just remove the `$` from the end of your expression.

You also don't need the nested (unnamed) capturing group around `console|file`. The named capturing group is sufficient.